# Scraping Options Data from Google Finance using R

Tags: r, json, trading

I recently saw a function that will scrape [Options Data from Google Finance](https://mktstk.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/start-trading-like-a-quant-download-option-chains-from-google-finance-in-r/)

It works fine, but I am trying to use the function to call 20 different stocks (although some of them do not have options data) and save them as a list....

I have modified the `getOptionQuote` function to fit my needs:

Functions provided from the site above:

```
# installs RCurl and jsonlite packages. will prompt you to select mirror for download
install.packages("RCurl");library("RCurl")
install.packages("jsonlite");library("jsonlite")
# ******************************************************************

getOC2 <- function(symbol){
  output = list()
  url = paste('http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=', symbol, '&output=json', sep = "")
  x = getURL(url)
  fix = fixJSON(x)
  json = fromJSON(fix)
  numExp = dim(json$expirations)[1]
if(length(numExp)!= 0){
    for(i in 1:numExp){
    # download each expirations data
    y = json$expirations[i,]$y
    m = json$expirations[i,]$m
    d = json$expirations[i,]$d
    expName = paste(y, m, d, sep = "_")
    if (i > 1){
      url = paste('http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=', symbol, '&output=json&expy=', y, '&expm=', m, '&expd=', d, sep = "")
      json = fromJSON(fixJSON(getURL(url)))
    }
    output[[paste(expName, "calls", sep = "_")]] = json$calls
    output[[paste(expName, "puts", sep = "_")]] = json$puts
  }}
  assign(paste(symbol),do.call(rbind,output))
}




fixJSON <- function(json_str){
  stuff = c('cid','cp','s','cs','vol','expiry','underlying_id','underlying_price',
            'p','c','oi','e','b','strike','a','name','puts','calls','expirations',
            'y','m','d')

  for(i in 1:length(stuff)){
    replacement1 = paste(',"', stuff[i], '":', sep = "")
    replacement2 = paste('\\{"', stuff[i], '":', sep = "")
    regex1 = paste(',', stuff[i], ':', sep = "")
    regex2 = paste('\\{', stuff[i], ':', sep = "")
    json_str = gsub(regex1, replacement1, json_str)
    json_str = gsub(regex2, replacement2, json_str)
  }
  return(json_str)
}
```

I have basically added the `if(length(numExp)!= 0){` to accomodate for stocks that do not have options chains....

Here is what I use to call the 20 stocks:

```
LIST <- c("AAMC", "AAU", "ACU", "ACY", "ADGE", "ADK", "AE", "AIII", "AINC", 
"AIRI", "AKG", "ALN", "ALTV", "AMCO", "AMPE", "AMS", "APP", "APT", 
"APTS", "ASM")

library("plyr")

# USE PARALLEL COMPUTING FOR FASTER PROCESS
registerDoParallel(detectCores())


system.time(
  OC <- llply(.data=as.list(LIST), .fun=function(x) {
    tmp <- try(getOC2(x))
    if (!inherits(tmp, 'try-error')) tmp
  }, .parallel = TRUE, .paropts=list(c(.packages=(all.available=T))))
)

#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.008   0.001   0.097
```

I get no errors but `OC` should have a length of 20, however it only has a length on 1 and produces: `list(NULL)`

SESSION INFO:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.3       doMC_1.3.3       doParallel_1.0.8 iterators_1.0.7  foreach_1.4.2    pbapply_1.1-1    jsonlite_0.9.17 
 [9] RCurl_1.95-4.7   bitops_1.0-6    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0                   lattice_0.20-33               codetools_0.2-14              zoo_1.7-12                   
 [5] grid_3.2.2                    magrittr_1.5                  PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 stringi_0.5-5                
 [9] PortfolioAnalytics_1.0.3636   xts_0.9-7                     blotter_0.8.19                tools_3.2.2                  
[13] compiler_3.2.2                quantstrat_0.8.2
```

Comment: [Data APIs/feeds available as packages in R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12670/data-apis-feeds-available-as-packages-in-r)

Comment: the closest function is via Quantmod but currently supports calling option data from yahoo only @hrbrmstr